# Why some users are not getting Approval notification nor approval emails from our "Start and wait for an approval" action

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-teams, approval

I have the following "Start and wait for approval":-

[image]
&
[image]

where the approval will be sent to 2 users, currently only one user will get the approval email/notification, while the other user will never get approval email or notification (even if the first user did not response).. any idea what could be the issue. For example for more than hour a running flow is hang on the approval step:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but I can only suggest the following.

- trace the output of [List group members], verify whether the email addresses returned are valid.
- When both emails are valid, verify in your Azure AD whether both users have their email address set as "Alternate email address" in another Azure AD account.
- I know it sounds weird, but did the second user ever go to https://flow.microsoft.com once and click Sign In?

I notice that your way of sending approval is not common. Or do you intend to ask approval serially?